# List Comprehension output different than nested for loops?

Tags: python

I really am at a loss as to why this list comprehension is generating different output to what I thought the equivalent with nested for loops. Can anyone shed any insight?

The list comprehension:

```
[(n ** 5, m ** 3) for n in range(3) for m in range(5) if m % 2 == 0]
```

Results in the following:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 8), (0, 64), (1, 0), (1, 8), (1, 64), (32, 0), (32, 8), (32, 64)]
```

However, what I believe is the equivalent nested For loop:

```
L = []
for n in range(3):
    for m in range(5):
        if m % 2 == 0:
            n = n**5
            m = m**3
            vals = (n,m)
            L.append(vals)
L
```

Results in the following:

```
[(0, 0),
 (0, 8),
 (0, 64),
 (1, 0),
 (1, 8),
 (1, 64),
 (32, 0),
 (33554432, 8),
 (42535295865117307932921825928971026432, 64)]
```

Why is there a difference in the output between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loop is not equivalent to the list comprehension, because you have altered `n` in the inner loop:

```
n = n**5
```

For any value other than `0` or `1` this increases `n` exponentially. So for the last iteration of the outer loop `n = 2` is set, but then you assign `2 ** 5 = 32` to `n`, and then `32 ** 5 = 33554432`.

Use a different name:

```
L = []
for n in range(3):
    for m in range(5):
        if m % 2 == 0:
            n_power_5 = n**5
            m_power_3 = m**3
            vals = (n_power_5, m_power_3)
            L.append(vals)
```

or just don't use intermediate variables at all:

```
for n in range(3):
    for m in range(5):
        if m % 2 == 0:
            L.append((n**5, m**3))
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn. Could I ask you what the equivalent nested for loop should be? That would aid my understanding.

Comment: @jsynnott Don't do those separate assignments, just do `vals = (n**5, m**3)`

Comment: @jsynnott: use a different name.